chupah and halachot of yichud

Do we paskin that after the chupah you're totally married or only after yichud?

does the yichud room by a wedding need to be locked? Do the witnesses of the yichud make it secluded as if the door is physically locked? is there any reason to say, or shitos that hold that the door needs to be physically locked, and witnesses standing outside won't be good enough to make the room secluded for yichud standards regarding marriage?



Define "totally married"

not just she being assur to anyone else but also you being nutar to eachother, kesubah,you own her possessions etc.

https://etzion.org.il/en/halakha/even-haezer/marriage-and-divorce/laws-wedding-12-customs-and-laws-wedding
